# How to refresh data without screen flashing angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a chat based on simple get and post using some php and AngularJS. Since a chat requires data to be refreshed constantly , I was wondering what is the best way to refresh data? How I did it was

```
$scope.LoadData = function () {     

$http.get('php/getchatmessages.php')
    .then(
        function (response) {
            $scope.data.messages = [];
            $scope.data.messages = response.data;

            $scope.evid = $scope.data.messages[0].EventID;
        },
        function (response) {
            alert(response.data);
        }
    );      

    $interval(function(){$scope.LoadData()},5000);
};
```

This not only cause screen flickers, but the speed of the refresh speeds up over time, taking a lot of processor power and slowly crashes the browser.

Comment: The refreshing is happening because you clear all the messages and then you add them back again. You should only push to $scope.data.messages the new messages rather than deleting everything. Also, for this kind of application is better to use Web Sockets.

Comment: @RocoCTZ how do I get the new changes only? Yes I've heard of web sockets but I looking for the simpler solution as time is constrained

Comment: In your view, assuming all messages have an ID and you use ng-repeat, use `ng-repeat="message in data.messages track by message.id"`. This makes ure angular doesn't remove all the elements and recreate them, but updates the existing dom nodes instead. Also, remove the line `$scope.data.messages = [];`, which doesn't hurt, but is completely useless.

Comment: Also, remove the call to $interval from the LoadData function: each time you load a data, you start a new job that will load the dtaa every 5 seconds. That makes no sense.

Comment: @Lessy You get the changes only by manually comparing the current messages array with the array that you get from the back-end. It's ugly, but only because you are using the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

**What is the best way to refresh data?**

I would recommend looking into [socket.io](http://socket.io/) which enables real time communication via the WebSocket API. They also have a [chat demo](http://socket.io/demos/chat/). I believe WebSocket's are the **best way to refresh data** in your case.

If WebSockets are not an option for you, then your method will work if you fix your current issues:

**The speed of the refresh speeds up over time**

This is because you are calling `$interval(function(){$scope.LoadData()},5000);` inside `$scope.LoadData`. Move it outside the function so it doesn't start a new interval every call.

**Taking a lot of processor power and slowly crashes the browser**

If you are simply replacing the exiting message array with the new from the response then **remove** `$scope.data.messages = [];` and you will stop the screen  from "flickering".

As for the data issue, you should think about **retrieving only new messages** instead of getting all of them at once. This way you can **simply append the new data to your messages array**. This is dramatically improve performance by minimising response sizes.

Answer (score 0):

The flicker speeds up because you use [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) in each invocation, which is PERIODIC and adds another invocation afterwards. Either use [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) which only adds one invocation, or call `$interval` outside of `LoadData`.

Comment: yes, every time you call LoadData, an $interval object (believe its a promise), is created, therefore you effectively have a bunch of $intervals running causing the faster flickering and browser crashing.  put outside LoadData so you only have one $interval going every 5 seconds instead of a lot at many different times